# How can I see all installed third-party components, packages and extensions?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria, delphi-ide

I have many third-party components, packages, and extensions installed on my Delphi. Some of them appear on the splash screen, but not all of them.

A while ago I installed a certain package and IDE extension, but now I can't find it. So that's why I'm wondering if there's a place or a way I can see all of my installed third-party things.

I know if you install something from the GetIt Package Manager, then it's simple. I can just view all installed ones in GetIt, but what if I installed it outside of GetIt.

So my question... How/Where can I see everything that I have installed on my Delphi?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- There is the window menu item "*C̲omponent > Install P̲ackages...*" which lists all design time packages.
- [GExperts has an "Expert Manager"](https://gexperts.org/tour/index.html?expert_manager.html) for DLL experts.
- The "*Version info*" button in Delphi's "*H̲elp > A̲bout...*" box shows 3rd party DLLs too.

Comment: This is also true for old versions (f.e. Delphi 7). Per highlighted design package you can see its filename below and click the "_Components_" button for listing all which are in that package. Don't expect the window menu item to be available when your project is currently running.